# Export to HAR file unsuccessfull: Error while processing HAR file: c.f.j.d.JsonMappingException: String length exceeds maximum length

Tags: gatling

[image]

I updated to Gatling 3.9.3 and started getting this error. Earlier my gatling version was 3.9.0 and the same HAR file was successfully converted in the recorder. Now I am getting the below error.

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub and provide your HAR file. It looks like Jackson introduced some extra security limits.

Comment: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4407
pleas check, thanlks!